# Import script from a different directory

Tags: python, function, import, module, directory

I would like to know how I can import a python script into my main script from a different directory (in this case, the parent directory).

I have used the following code to append the parent directory to the sys.path list, and then import the script (main.py) in order to use functions inside this file:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("../"))
from main import draw_text_on_screen
```

However, when I call this function from the main.py script, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'main.py'; main is not a package
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Or, is there another way to import modules where I can specify the full directory path?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

When I made a folder `parent` with the Pythonscript `parent.py` and made another folder in `parent` called `child`, containing `child.py` I was able to import (and use) all the functions of `parent.py` in `child.py` with the following code:

**child.py**

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("../"))

from parent import myFunction

myFunction()
```

**parent.py**

```
def myFunction():
    print('Hi there')
```

**Console output:**

```
> C:\Users\Rick\Desktop\parent\child>child.py
Hi there
```